# Jquery post loop with array

Tags: jquery, loops, post

i want to post loop with array. I need something like; i have tried many method cant figure it out.

```
var fid=["62727","373837",273737"...."2838"]

$(document).ready(function(){
        $.post("edit_"fid[0]".xhtml", 
     {           
       }
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.post("edit_"fid[1]".xhtml", 
     {           
       }
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.post("edit_"fid[2]".xhtml", 
     {           
       }
.
.
.
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.post("edit_"fid[n]".xhtml", 
     {           
       }
```

i tried with js loop. but maybe i am missing something or maybe its not the proper way to.  Here is my code. This works only with last index variable .

```
<input name="mif" value="stechnid"/> 
<input value="newid" name="mifs"/>    

<div id="msginf0"></div> 
<div id="msginf1"></div> 
<div id="msginf2"></div> 
<div id="msginf3"></div> 
<div id="msginf4"></div> 
<div id="msginf5"></div> 
<div id="msginf6"></div> 
<div id="msginf7"></div> 





var mif=document.getElementsByName('mif')[0].value;
var mifs=document.getElementsByName('mifs')[0].value;

var pid = ["112233", "112234", "12343", "4433", "7357", "272272"];
var ac = pid.length;
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < ac; i++) {

var txt=mif.replace(/stechnid/ig, pid[i]); 

$(document).ready(function(){
        $.post("edit_"+pid[0]+".xhtml", 
     {           
         ownform: txt,           
         msg_separator: "",
         nfv: "msg_separator",
         siteform: mifs,            
         action: "edit_WAP2_fchOWN",
         type: "forum",
         hash: ":admin-hash:",
         submit: "submit" },         


    function(data,status)
{  document.getElementById("msginf"+i).innerHTML="success"+i+pid[i]+txt; 

       });  
    });
   }
```

alternative or easiest way is fine by me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, $(document).ready goes outside the loop, you only need one-time listener for the document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var mif = $('[name=mif]').val(); //the jQuery way
   ...
   ...
   var fid=["62727","373837",273737"...."2838"];
   var otherVars;
   .....
   .....
   for(i = 0; i < fid.length; i++) {
     $.post('', {
     ....
     ....
     });
   }
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
   
var fid=["62727","373837",273737","2838"];

for(i = 0; i < fid.length; i++) {

$.post("edit_0.xhtml", 
     {           
         ownform: "",           
         msg_separator: "",
         nfv: "msg_separator",
         siteform: "",            
         action: "edit_WAP2_fchOWN",
         type: "forum",
         hash: ":admin-hash:",
         submit: "submit" },         


    function(data,status)
{  document.getElementById("msginf"+i).innerHTML="success+i"; 
     
       });
   }
});

Comment: it doesn't response.

Comment: Can you tell me what i did wrong or can you please fix it?